# How to bypass windows start screen & other

Tags: windows, desktop

I would like to know if there is a way of bypassing the windows start screen / login screen. What i want is that, when i start the pc the only thing the user sees is my app. If it helps in any way my app will be made using visual.

Does anyone know how do i go about doing this?

Comment: You're looking for *Windows kiosk mode*. A search on that phrase should help you find intormation.

Comment: Thank you for the help. In kiosk mode does the user not have to put a password, and does the user not see the windows logo we the pc starts?

Comment: Did you Google the phrase I gave you to find information, or are you expecting me to do it for you?

Comment: I did. In a quick reading i did not seem to find anything regarding the starting windows animation. In my project the user is going to be able to start and shutdown the machine physically, so i do not want the user to see any windows lifeforms at all.